# Удаленная проверка установленных обновлений Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, сеть, update

Появилась интересная задача на работе. Имеются сервера КИПиА, которые иногда могут сбоить и так далее. После сбоя проводят развертывание образа и часто бывает, что в данном образе не хватает нужных обновлений. Служба безопасности приезжает на проверки и через "Панель управления->Программы и компоненты->Установленные обновления" и сверяет со списком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Поэтому встала задача о написании приложении, которое по локальной сети бы собирала информацию с серверов о установленных обновлений, в случае отсутствия его в списках выдавала, что такого-то обновления нет.

Сервера находятся в своей подсети, доступ в интернет ограничен, Active Directory не настроен, WSUS не стоит.

Поэтому пару вопросов.

1) Может уже есть готовые аналоги, проверяющие всё это дело?

2) Получение списка обновлений через команду

```
wmic qfe get
```

выдает не все обновления. 
Использовал WMI запросы (Win32_QuickFixEngineering: [пример на гитхабе](https://github.com/OlegBezverhii/UpdatesList/blob/master/ConsoleUpdate/Program.cs)) - выдает тоже самое, что и wmic.

Получается, что можно получить весь список только через WUAPI или есть ещё какие-то способы?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-hotfix?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Вот [тут](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4197.windows-how-to-list-all-of-the-windows-and-software-updates-applied-to-a-computer.aspx) еще стоит почитать. Правда на английском.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            object sess=null;
            object search = null;
            object coll = null;

            try
            {
                sess = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session","compname"));
                search = (sess as dynamic).CreateUpdateSearcher();

                int n = (search as dynamic).GetTotalHistoryCount();
                coll = (search as dynamic).QueryHistory(1, n);

                Console.WriteLine("Updates");
                foreach (dynamic item in coll as dynamic)
                {
                    if (item.Operation == 1) Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sess != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sess);
                if (search != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(search);
                if (coll != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(coll);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за код. Ну это получается как я выше писал, что через WUA (Windows Update Agent), только способ немного другой (я делал как везде пишут - через wuapi.dll)

Answer (score 0):

https://habr.com/ru/post/467445/ - написал целую статью по этому поводу. Результат один - используйте WMI. Проект на гитхабе с реализацией всех методов: https://github.com/OlegBezverhii/List-Update-Cheker

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]